# Ignore margin in case div is empty

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have 2 DIVs aligned horizontally next to each other and centred using a wrapper.
I use margin-right to separate DIV2 from DIV1.
DIV2 could have no content. In case DIV2 has no content, i want the margin to be ignored and DIV1 to be centred alone.

This is my CSS:

```
#div1 {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     margin-left: 200px;
}
#div2 {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

This is HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
     <div id="div1">Div1</div>
     <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

I created a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/wfrcG/3/

Is there a way in CSS to achieve this without javascript?

Answer (score 17):

You could use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) pseudo class to set the margin to `0` if the element is empty.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jr8Ux/)

```
#div2:empty {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `:empty` is not applied if `div` contains (only) whitespaces!