# Grab every 3rd li but not if it has children and a class assigend?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I'm recently learning CSS and wanted to figure something out for my site but cannot comprehend how to do this.

I want to garb every third li (beginning with the second li) except I dont want it if its either

1) Has any children (content is being fetched from DB, when li's empty it will have nothing insdie, when it has content it has ,

, etc.)

2) Has a class assigned to it.

Is this possible with css or javascript?

Thank you!!

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    .....
</ol>
```

Comment: A more complete example would be helpful. This is just a generic `ol`.

Comment: I though to simplify it. In reality the lis contain images and info from database but structure is same. Sometimes there is no info from DB in the li and that is why I want to grab it with css.

Comment: Also IF li is empty it has nothing insde of it.

Comment: This sees like an extreme case better suited to a simpler approach than such a complex selector.

Comment: @user2930185 Your example isn't simple, it is incomplete. Notice how web-tiki's HTML handles all of the cases. HTML like that is what you should strive for. It is simple, but **complete**. Obviously, they figured out what you wanted, I'm just trying to explain what I meant with my original comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

web-tiki's updated jsfiddle is pretty right on (so the downvote seemed unnecessary), but it is actually possible to check that you're only selecting empty `<li>` by using `:empty`:

```
li:nth-child(3n+2):empty:not(.selected) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: @user2930185 Give [web-tiki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394533/2680216) some credit too - you dismissed his answer and stating it ["does not help"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394352/grab-every-3rd-li-but-not-if-it-has-children-and-a-class-assigend#comment35841777_23394533). It is surely the basis of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

For the children, <strike>I don't think it will be possible only with CSS</strike> **[It is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394695/1811992).** but for every third li without a class it is with `li:nth-child(3n+2):not(.selected)`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hC5R2/)**

```
li{
    width:30%;
    background:gold;
    margin:5px;
}
li:nth-child(3n+2):not(.selected){
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: This does not help. I need beginining from SECOND li and I need li if it doesnt have a child

Comment: @user2930185 Sorry for the SECOND li, here you are : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hC5R2/1/

Comment: this is close but not quite. most important thing is rto check if it has children. because when nothing is returned from DB the li's are empty. please see if you can figure htis out. thank you!!

Comment: @user2930185 I am trying to help and my answer is getting you closer than before to your aim even if It doesn't fill ALL your requirements so you could have a little respect for what I am doing...

Comment: 1+ .. @web-tiki You can also use the [`:empty` pseudo class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378296/ignore-margin-in-case-div-is-empty/23378323#23378323).

Comment: @null I know that... But, based on the OP's comment - *"Also IF li is empty it has nothing insde of it."* it should work.